# Succesive vs simultaneous blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying blow-ups of varieties and there's some things which seems confusing to me.

1. Denote by $Z={\rm Bl}_{x_1,x_2}(X)$ the blow-up of two points $x_1, x_2\in X$. Under what conditions $Z$ is isomorphic to succesive blow-up ${\rm Bl}_{p^{-1}(x_2)}({\rm Bl}_{x_1}X)$ (where $p$ is the first blow-up $p: {\rm Bl}_{x_1}X\to X$).
2. Does the number of blown up points matter (say, we pick more than 2 points)?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

1. This should be at least be true for smooth complete varieties over $\mathbb{C}$
2. Doesn't matter.

Comment: This is not a particularly helpful answer. Can you give some reasons why your answer is true?

Comment: This is the hypothesis I've seen given for the "Weak Factorization Theorem"

Comment: www.math.purdue.edu/~wlodar/Madrid3.pdf